# Vertical line at specific data point

Tags: plot, gnuplot

I have a set of csv-data like this:

```
1,-3
2,-1
3,0
4,3
5,6
6,1
7,-2
```

What I'm trying to achieve is an automatically created vertical line at y=0. Plotting the point is no problem via linespoints:

```
plot 'data.dat' u 1:($6 == 0.0 ? $6 : 1/0) w lp
```

What I do not understand yet is, how to get the value to be used in an arrow to create the desired vertical line.

Edit: Also, it is possible that there is more than one point with y=0 - but I only need the first one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use a recent version of gnuplot which include the command `stats`:

```
stat 'data.dat' u ($2 == 0.0 ? $1 : 1/0) 
print STATS_min
set arrow 99 from first STATS_min, graph 0 to first STATS_min, graph 1
```

Comment: I had to flip your comment since I needed a vertical line. Now it works like a charm. Thanks!